# Python: splitting money value (represented as Decimal with 2 significant places) into X equal parts

Tags: python

I have the following problem: I have a decimal value representing money, with 2 decimal places. I need to split it into X equal parts also represented as decimals with 2 decimal places.

Example 1: splitting 1.04 (1 dollar and 4 cents) into 3 equal parts should give: 0.35, 0.35, 0.34

Example 2: splitting 0.01 (1 cent) into 3 equal parts should give: 0.01, 0.00, 0.00

and so on.

Comment: what did you try so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you:

```
money = 1.04
n = 3
lst = []
divided = round(money/n,2)
for x in range(n):
    if sum(lst) == money:
        lst.append(0.0)
    elif x == n-1:
        lst.append(round(money-sum(lst),2))
    else:
        lst.append(divided)

lst.sort(reverse=True)
print(lst)
```

Output:

```
[0.35, 0.35, 0.34]
```

Comment: Sorry, but it does not work for example with `money = 0.04` and `n = 4` @PawelRoman

Comment: Is it so? This was the output that I got for `money = 0.04` and `n = 4`: `[0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01]`

Comment: oups, I made a mistake. I wanted to write that it does not work with `money = 0.04` and `n = 6`. I got the output: `[0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, -0.01]`

Comment: Oh yeah. Thanks for pointing out the bug! I have edited my code. Check out whether my edited version of the code works correctly.

Comment: It still does not work for example with `money=0.06` and `n=4`: it gives `[0.03, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01]`

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you using the integer division to find the result.
Here is an example, that I find easily readable:

```
def func(money,n):
    q = round(((money * 100) // n) / 100, 2)  # quotient
    r = int(money * 100 % n)                  # remainder
    q1 = round(q + 0.01, 2)                   # quotient + 0.01
    result = [q1] * r + [q] * (n-r)
    return result

print(func(1.04,3))  # [0.35, 0.35, 0.34]
print(func(0.01,3))  # [0.01, 0.0, 0.0]
```

Comment: To those that may use this answer, be aware that it might not work for some floats, e.g. `0.29` where it returns `[0.14, 0.14]` but it should be (not considering order) `[0.14, 0.15]`.